# Blender Fluid Simulation does not work even after baking at 300 Resolution subdiv

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I created a fluid simulation with a domain and a flow mesh, and baked it even at 300 resolution, but still no fluid appears in the scene.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can check the blend file, but first is it possible that the normals on your emitter mesh are inverted?

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard: nearly... ;) emitters faces are not inverted, but a lot other faces are, and i think you should first fix that. Then update your blend file and i will check again. e.g. your trunks...[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdDEd.png